# MSACCESS I want to get calculated all records before a particular month and year

Tags: vb.net

I have searched on google but didnt found the right answer...
I am calculating invoice in VB.net using access data base
I have to get all records before and from this Month-year
like date <= Feb,2014 i dont want day option in it...

I have two tables

Customer table

```
+--------+---------+
| refno  | deposit |
+--------+---------+
| 1/13   |     -10 |
| 10/13  |     500 |
| 100/13 |       0 |
| 101/13 |     250 |
| 102/13 |    1000 |
+--------+---------+
```

Ledger Table

```
+--------+----------+------+----------+
| refno  | quantity | rate | recieved |
+--------+----------+------+----------+
| 1/13   |        2 |   70 |        0 |
| 10/13  |        3 |   80 |        0 |
| 100/13 |        0 |    0 |      500 |
| 101/13 |        4 |   60 |        0 |
| 102/13 |       10 |   65 |        0 |
+--------+----------+------+----------+
```

I want to customer (deposit) added in ledger (total) 
I used this query

```
"select (sum(l.quantity*l.rate-l.recieved)+first(c.openbal)) as total from customer c RIGHT JOIN ledger l ON l.refno = c.refno having l.refno='" & LV_cinfo.Items(i).Text & "'"
```

Now I want to calculate thios total upto the selected month date <= Feb,2014

```
refno | total = customer.deposit+(ledger.quantity*ledger.rate-ledger.received)
1/13  | -200
10/13 | 4210
100/13| 625
101/13| 280
102/13| 1000
```

Regards,

Comment: Very poor description of your problem. Try to be more precise. What is the name of your table? What are the column names that are involved (Amount, Dates etc...) and more important, what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Steve I have edited the question ope you will understand

Comment: None of the information above shows any dates. How do you differentiate between items sold in each month?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT COUNT(<Column Name>) FROM <Table Name> WHERE (Date Between #<From Date># AND #<Till Date>#

Column Name : Primary Key Column Name
Table Name  : Data Table Name
From Date   : Starting Date
Till Date   : Ending Date
```